# Self-Hosted WCF Service with Mutual SSL (between Service and Client) fails with 403 Forbidden

Tags: wcf, ssl, https, mutual-authentication

I’m trying to setup a demo of Mutual SSL between a *self-hosted* WCF service and a client app (command prompt for now).  In the end I’m trying to get to a solution where I have *transport security* (not message security) between a server that uses a certificate for its incoming connections and multiple clients each with individual certs that I can use to uniquely identify each of the clients.

I’ve tried a number of differing approaches to this, but none have worked (I was unable to find an exact example for what I’ve been trying to do).  Each time I think I’m getting close I end up with an exception in the client when I try to invoke the service.  The most common exception I’ve run into is:

```
“The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.”
Inner exception: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I might have done wrong or perhaps a better walk through of how to setup mutual SSL in the above scenario?

Full disclosure - as of right now I am running both the client and server on the same computer.  Not sure if that matters.

Config snippets below

The service and client code is relatively trivial so I’m pretty confident that I’ve gotten them to work.  The app configs (specifically the bindings and behaviors) and certs are “more interesting” so I’m not as confident there.

How I created the certs (actual commands verbatim)

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=SelfSignedCA" -ss Root -sr LocalMachine  -a sha1 -sky signature -r -sv "SelfSignedCA.cer" "SelfSignedCA.pvk"
makecert -pe -n "CN=system" -ss my -sr LocalMachine -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1  -in "SelfSignedCA" -is Root -ir LocalMachine -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 Service.cer
makecert -pe -n "CN=client1" -ss my -sr LocalMachine -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1  -in "SelfSignedCA" -is Root -ir LocalMachine -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 Client1.cer
```

Associating the Cert with the port (actual commands verbatim)

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:44355/MyService/ user=EVERYONE
```

**Server Settings**

Bindings:

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding">      
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Behaviors:

```
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
      <!--
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate
           findValue="system"
           storeLocation="LocalMachine"
           storeName="My"
           x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
      -->
      <serviceAuthorization
         serviceAuthorizationManagerType=
              "ClientAuthorization.ClientCertificateAuthorizationManager, Simulator.Service.SideA" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

**Client**

Bindings:

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CustomBinding">      
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Behaviors

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ChannelManagerBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
         <clientCertificate findValue="client1"
                           storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                           storeName="My"
                           x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <!--
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
        </serviceCertificate>
        -->
      </clientCredentials>
     </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

**UPDATE**

So I added a custom username and password validator to the server in an attempt to override the default behavior and always allow regardless of the credentials presented (again I really don't want username/password validation).  **This validator never gets invoked.**  The Client still gets the "authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.” exception.

Service Behavior Update

```
  <serviceCredentials>
    <userNameAuthentication 
      userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
      customUserNamePasswordValidatorType=
        "Service.ClientAuthorization.ClientUserNamePasswordValidatorManager, Service.SideA" />
  </serviceCredentials>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the demo for your reference. i tested it under win7 + vs2010 + client-server-on-same-machine.

server side:

```
[ServiceContract(Name="CalculatorService")]
    public interface ICalculatorService {
        [OperationContract]
        int Add(int x, int y);
    }

public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService {
        public Int32 Add(Int32 x, Int32 y) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: service method called (x = {1}, y = {2})",
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, x, y);
            return x + y;
        }
    }

class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            using (var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService))) {
                serviceHost.Opened += delegate {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: service started", 
                        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                };
                serviceHost.Open();
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="transportSecurity">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <services>
            <service name="WcfService.CalculatorService">
                <endpoint address="https://hp-laptop:3721/calculatorservice"
                          binding="wsHttpBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="transportSecurity"
                          contract="Contract.ICalculatorService" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel> </configuration>
```

Client side:

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using (var channelFactory =
                new ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService>("calculatorservice")) {
                ICalculatorService proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
                Console.WriteLine(proxy.Add(1, 2));
                Console.Read();
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="transportSecurity">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="defaultClientCertificate">
                    <clientCredentials>
                        <clientCertificate 
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                            storeName="My" 
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" 
                            findValue="client1"/>
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <client>
            <endpoint name="calculatorservice" behaviorConfiguration="defaultClientCertificate"
                      address="https://hp-laptop:3721/calculatorservice"
                      binding="wsHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="transportSecurity"
                      contract="Contract.ICalculatorService"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Certificate creation:

self-created CA

> makecert -n "CN=RootCA" -r -sv c:\rootca.pvk c:\rootca.cer

After creation, import this certificate into 'Trusted Root Certification' by Certificates Console. This is the step to stop the exception you mentioned.

certificate for service program

> makecert -n "CN=hp-laptop" -ic c:\rootca.cer -iv c:\rootca.pvk -sr
>   LocalMachine -ss My -pe -sky exchange

Note that the CN value above should match to the DNS part of service address. e.g. hp-laptop is my computer name. the address of service endpoint will be "https://google.com:/...".  (replace google dot com with 'hp-laptop' due to some stackoverflow rules).

register service certificate with service program:

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:3721
>   certhash=‎6c78ad6480d62f5f460f17f70ef9660076872326
>   appid={a0327398-4069-4d2d-83c0-a0d5e6cc71b5}

The certhash value is the thumbprint of service program certificate (check with Certificates Console). the appid is the GUID from service program file "AssemblyINfo.cs".

Certicate for client program:

> makecert -n "CN=client1" -ic c:\rootca.cer -iv c:\rootca.pvk -sr
>   LocalMachine -ss My -pe -sky exchange

UPDATE: according to typhoid's experience with this solution, the 'Anonymous' exception is still there due to too many trusted root authorities in that server. Two links was provided by typhoid to solve this issue.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2464556

http://blog.codit.eu/post/2013/04/03/Troubleshooting-SSL-client-certificate-issue-on-IIS.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your notes.  This all makes sense to me and it was very easy to follow.  However, I followed your sample code/steps twice and in both cases I see see the "authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.” exception in the client when it makes the call to "proxy.Add(1, 2)".   BTW I am using Win 7 & VS 2012

Comment: have you imported rootCA certificate into the Certificates console (type 'mmc' in Windows RUN and add Certificates into mmc. remember to select 'Local Computer' instead of current user). I got the same error before doing this step.

Comment: Yes I have the "RootCA" certificate present under Console Root -> Certificates (Local Computer) -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificates.

I also have client1 and [my machine] certificates present under Console Root -> Certificates (Local Computer) -> Personal -> Certificates.  Both of these chain up to RootCA without error.

Comment: Just noticed this ... in the service if you break after the serviceHost.Open() statement and then drill into serviceHost->base->Authorization I see the "PrincipalPermissionMode" set to "UseWindowsGroups".

Comment: When I browse to https://localhost:44444/calculatorservice/ (I'm using a different port from you) in IE I get the same HTTP 403 error.

Comment: we can't change it to port 44444. because netsh command has bind port 3721 to the certificate for service.

Comment: Could you expand on "After creation, import this certificate into 'Trusted Root Certification' by Certificates Console. This is the step to stop the exception you mentioned." ... Are you saying to import rootca.cer into Certificates (Local Computer or Current User) -> Trusted Root Certification Autorities -> Certificates

Comment: exactly. last night i created a new project with source code sections that i put in this answer at home. it works fine. just can't find which part causes the authentication scheme 'Anonymous' exception. i guess the problem is still with certificate creation part. I got this exception before when the created root certificate was not in the trusted root CA list. But once it's in that list, that exception wouldn't show up any more.

Comment: Hrm ... still not working.  I followed your steps above again (this time I did *not* change the port) and I'm still getting the same exception.  Right now the only differences I see between our setups is I'm using VS 2012.  Can you post your solution and cert files for me to use to try to rule out something quirky with this machine?

Comment: Got it!! Looks like there is a MS limit/bug that I was running up to . Basically I have too many trusted root authorities on the server that it was hitting a memory limit when building the trusted root chain. 

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2464556  
http://blog.codit.eu/post/2013/04/03/Troubleshooting-SSL-client-certificate-issue-on-IIS.aspx

Please add these two links to your solution and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to [monitor the actual exchange](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabs/archive/2012/04/27/monitor-certificate-ssl-handshake.aspx) including the ssl v3 handshake.  I ran into something similar and eventually discovered that the SSL Handshake was failing because I had too many trusted certificate authorities.  To resolve this, I needed to follow [this resolution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2801679).  The resolution keeps the SSL portion of windows from sending the trusted certificate authorities back to the client; thus, allowing the handshake to complete.

Comment: This was the problem I was encountering.  yyou has added these notes to his solution to provide a complete solution to the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I ran into this issue today (in 2018) and your solution did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for several days until finally, I realized that this line creates a "Server Authentication" certificate. You need a "Client Authentication" certificate or the client certificate will be considered invalid.

> makecert -pe -n "CN=client1" -ss my -sr LocalMachine -a sha1 -sky
>   exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1  -in "SelfSignedCA" -is Root -ir
>   LocalMachine -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy
>   12 Client1.cer

So just use a **2** for the `-eku` parameter instead: `1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2`

Answer (score 0):

The SSL handshake must complete successfully before any HTTP traffic can go through.  The fact that you are getting an HTTP response at all indicates that your SSL setup is working fine.

The 403 Forbidden response indicates that the server is set up to require HTTP basic auth username and password before providing the resource/page.  You need your clients to provide the basic auth username/password at the HTTP level, in addition to what you are already doing at the TLS/SSL level, or you need to set up the server to allow access without HTTP basic auth.

Comment: I'd like to allow anonymous access, and perform the authorization based on the clients provided cert, but I don't seem to see a way to change the server's configuration to enable anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue (Forbidden 403) for my client trying to connect to server using MutualAuthentication.  It is true that SSL layer is not an issue and at the same time the Server did not get the request as it was blocked by transport layer.
But I was facing this for 2012 server only where-as 2008 would work just fine.
Enabling the serviceSecurityAudit at the Service configuration via

```
<serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application"
            suppressAuditFailure="false" 
            serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" 
            messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" />
```

showed the error/failure in the Windows Event log application side as Message Authentication and Service Authorization errors.

The solution which worked for me was to introduce a custom certificate validator for clientCertificate via

```
   <clientCertificate>              <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="App.Web.Framework.MyX509CertificateValidator, App.Vertical.Send"  />
   </clientCertificate>
```

This would require one to implement Certificate validation method in the assembly.

I can provide that detail as well if needed.

Thanks
--Kirti Kunal Shah